# Amazon Linux is blocking outgoing http calls

Tags: linux, curl, amazon-ec2

Suddenly my amazon EC2 instance has started blocking outbound http calls.
I tried doing a curl http://www.google.com and it finally came out with a Connection Timeout error. 
On enabling Verbose, it gave the following error:

```
 curl -v http://www.google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.217.3.164...
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::69...
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::69: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::69...
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::69: Network is unreachable
```

However, when i try curl with https, it works fine:

```
curl -v https://www.google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.217.3.164...
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.3.164) port 443 (#0)
```

I have another EC2 instance having the same security group, and everything's working fine on that instance.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your failing connections are all IPv6. As far as I know EC2 does not support IPv6 routing. So it makes sense that attempts to use it go nowhere.

I recommend discovering how to disable IPv6 networking in your OS image.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try disabling IPv6. However, since https calls are making it through, does the IPv6 possibility still stand?